# Ubuntu 14.10 server with LTSP and AMD Geode GX-MMX

Tags: 14.04, ati, ltsp

Already installed LTSP with

```
apt-get install ltsp-server-standalone
```

BUT ... anyone know this thin clients?
I don't know which `--arch` param use to build LTSP.

Answer (score 0):

Geode-GX are processors from 2002. I think that you should use i386 architecture.